# Typescript/Javascript: using tuple as key of Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hit this odd bug in my code and I can't figure the way to get a constant time lookup from a Map when using a tuple as my key.

Hopefully this illustrates the issue, and the workaround I'm using now just to get it to work:

hello.ts:

```
let map: Map<[number, number], number> = new Map<[number, number], number>()
    .set([0, 0], 48);

console.log(map.get([0,0])); // prints undefined

console.log(map.get(String([0, 0]))); //  compiler:  error TS2345: Argument of type 
// 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.

//the work-around:
map.forEach((value: number, key: [number, number]) => {
    if(String(key) === String([0, 0])){
        console.log(value); // prints 48
    }
})
```

To compile (transpile?) I'm using:

```
tsc hello.ts -target es6
```

tsc version 2.1.6

Tried several things to make the Map.get() method to work, not having much success.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In JavaScript (and as an extension, TypeScript), no two arrays are equal except if they refer to the same array (i.e., when changing the elements of one also would change the elements of another). If you create a new array with the same elements, it would not consider it to be equal to any existing one.

Because Maps consider such equality when looking up elements, if you store a value with an array as a key, you can only get the value out again if you pass in the exact same array reference as a key again:

```typescript
const map: Map<[ number, number], number> = new Map<[ number, number ], number>();

const a: [ number, number ] = [ 0, 0 ];
const b: [ number, number ] = [ 0, 0 ];

// a and b have the same value, but refer to different arrays so are not equal
a === b; // = false

map.set(a, 123);
map.get(a); // = 123
map.get(b); // = undefined
```

One simple workaround for this is to use strings or numbers as keys, as these are always considered equal when they have the same value:

```
const map: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

const a: [ number, number ] = [ 0, 0 ];
const b: [ number, number ] = [ 0, 0 ];

const astr: string = a.join(','); // = '0,0'
const bstr: string = b.join(','); // = '0,0'

// astr and bstr have the same value, and are strings so they are always equal
astr === bstr; // = true

map.set(astr, 123);
map.get(astr); // = 123
map.get(bstr); // = 123
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Meta point: there's a website that's literally lifted list comment without apparent attribution as a 'blog post': https://newbedev.com/typescript-javascript-using-tuple-as-key-of-map -- seems very shady.

Answer (score 11):

I would create my own class to do this so that I can easily use all of the map methods:

```
class MyMap {
    private map = new Map<string, number>();

    set(key: [number, number], value: number): this {
        this.map.set(JSON.stringify(key), value);
        return this;
    }

    get(key: [number, number]): number | undefined {
        return this.map.get(JSON.stringify(key));
    }

    clear() {
        this.map.clear();
    }

    delete(key: [number, number]): boolean {
        return this.map.delete(JSON.stringify(key));
    }

    has(key: [number, number]): boolean {
        return this.map.has(JSON.stringify(key));
    }

    get size() {
        return this.map.size;
    }

    forEach(callbackfn: (value: number, key: [number, number], map: Map<[number, number], number>) => void, thisArg?: any): void {
        this.map.forEach((value, key) => {
            callbackfn.call(thisArg, value, JSON.parse(key), this);
        });
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20value%3A%20number)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.set(JSON.stringify(key)%2C%20value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.get(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clear()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.clear()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20delete(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.delete(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20has(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.has(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20size()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.size%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20forEach(callbackfn%3A%20(value%3A%20number%2C%20key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20map%3A%20Map%3C%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20number%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20thisArg%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.forEach((value%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callbackfn.call(thisArg%2C%20value%2C%20JSON.parse(key)%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D#src=class%20MyMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20value%3A%20number)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.set(JSON.stringify(key)%2C%20value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.get(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clear()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.clear()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20delete(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.delete(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20has(key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.has(JSON.stringify(key))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20size()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.map.size%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20forEach(callbackfn%3A%20(value%3A%20number%2C%20key%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20map%3A%20Map%3C%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%2C%20number%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20thisArg%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.map.forEach((value%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callbackfn.call(thisArg%2C%20value%2C%20JSON.parse(key)%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20map%20%3D%20new%20MyMap()%3B%0D%0Amap.set(%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%204)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(map.get(%5B1%2C%202%5D))%20%2F%2F%204%0D%0A%0D%0Amap.set(%5B3%2C%204%5D%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0Amap.forEach((v%2C%20k)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(k%2C%20v))%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20prints%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%204%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B3%2C%204%5D%2020))

As you can see, the `forEach` for example will automatically give you the key as `[number, number]` instead of a string which you will then need to parse.

Usage example:

```
let map = new MyMap();
map.set([1, 2], 4);
console.log(map.get([1, 2])) // 4

map.set([3, 4], 20);
map.forEach((v, k) => console.log(k, v));
// prints:
// [1, 2] 4
// [3, 4] 20
```

Comment: There is also http://www.collectionsjs.com/ with which you can override contentEquals and contentHash methods to determine key equivalences.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases (e.g. when the second value in the tuple depends on the first value) I think it may be possible to use a nested map instead:

```js
// situation: a map from a tuple of (tableId, rowId) to the row's title

// instead of Map<[number, number], string> where the first number is
// tableId and the second number is rowId, we can have:
const rowTitleMap = Map<number, Map<number, string>>

const title = rowTitleMap.get(2)?.get(4) // can be string or undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this would work with Typescript or if there might be other downsides but this seems like a simple to use method to me that will retain the keys as tuples:

```js
const key_map_key_string = (tuple) => JSON.stringify(tuple);

const string_identical_tuple_key = (map_for_keying = new Map()) => {
  let key_map = new Map();
  [...map_for_keying.keys()].forEach((key) => key_map.set(key_map_key_string(key), key));

  return (tuple) => {
    const res = key_map.get(key_map_key_string(tuple));
    if(res) return res;

    key_map.set(key_map_key_string(tuple), tuple);
    return tuple;
  };
};

const test = () => {
  let a_map = new Map([
    [[1, 2], 'value1'],
    [[3, 4], 'value2']
  ]);
  
  const get_key = string_identical_tuple_key(a_map);
  
  console.log(a_map.get( get_key([1, 2]) ) === 'value1');
  
  a_map.set(get_key([5, 6]), 'value3');
  
  console.log(a_map.get( get_key([5, 6]) ) === 'value3');
  
  a_map.set(get_key([3, 4]), 'value4');
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify([...a_map]));
};

test();
```